# How to get data from JSON to HTML table using JS?

Tags: javascript

please help me get an html table from json like this:

```
{
    "accepted": [
        {
            "sum(bis)": 696
        }
    ],
    "processed": [
        {
            "bis": "220",
            "db": 0
        },
        {
            "bis": "152",
            "db": 0
        },
        {
            "bis": "152",
            "db": 456
        },
        {
            "bis": "152",
            "db": 356
        },
        {
            "bis": "22",
            "db": 320
        }
    ]
}
```

If "db": 0 then you need to indicate "-" in the table and output yes If "db": has any value then NO
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgbLU.jpg)
I tried to get data through a loop but I don’t have enough knowledge.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code.  If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: You need your server to provide the code.  Unless you are using Javascript on your web server (not client), this doesn't make sense.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the javascript api to write them to a html element.
Something like this :

```js
const jsonData = {
  "accepted": [{
    "sum(bis)": 696
  }],
  "processed": [{
      "bis": "220",
      "db": 0
    },
    {
      "bis": "152",
      "db": 0
    },
    {
      "bis": "152",
      "db": 456
    },
    {
      "bis": "152",
      "db": 356
    },
    {
      "bis": "22",
      "db": 320
    }
  ]
};

function createTable(data) {
  const table = document.createElement('table');
  const thead = document.createElement('thead');
  const tbody = document.createElement('tbody');

  // Create table header
  const headerRow = document.createElement('tr');
  Object.keys(data.processed[0]).forEach(key => {
    const th = document.createElement('th');
    th.textContent = key;
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  });
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  // Create table body
  data.processed.forEach(item => {
    const row = document.createElement('tr');
    Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      const td = document.createElement('td');
      // Check the condition for "db" value
      if (key === 'db') {
        td.textContent = value === 0 ? '-' : 'NO';
      } else {
        td.textContent = value;
      }
      row.appendChild(td);
    });
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  });
  table.appendChild(tbody);

  document.body.appendChild(table);
}

// Call the function with the provided JSON data
createTable(jsonData);
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>JSON to HTML Table</title>
</head>

</html>
```